# Attach file in Datasheet View

Tags: sharepoint-online, updatelistitems, datasheet

SharePoint 2007 allowed adding attachments to list items in Datasheet view. However, with SharePoint Online (Modern / Classic view) I do not get any options for attaching items in Datasheet view.

Is there a limitation or I am doing something wrong? I am the site owner where the list is created.